# I can apply the horizontal and vertical components of a Sobel operator. However, combining them introduces a lot of noise

Tags: python, image-processing, sobel

I am trying to manually implement a Sobel operator. Here is my code in Python 2.7:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

sobelX = np.array([[1,0,-1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])
sobelY = sobelX.T

imgoriginal = cv2.imread("building.bmp") 

imgv = cv2.filter2D(imgoriginal, -1, sobelY)
imgh = cv2.filter2D(imgoriginal, -1, sobelX)
imgboth = (imgv**2 + img**2)**0.5
```

And here is the output:

[image]

For some reason, the horizontal and vertical components of the operator seem to have good results, but the combined image has a lot of noise.

I notice when I do something like `(imgv**2)**0.5`, that also introduces a ton of noise, even though ideally, I should get approximately the same image back.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Am I supposed to combine the images a different way?

Comment: I don’t know for sure because I’m not very familiar with OpenCV,  it it is likely that this is caused by the data type of the image. With integer types you get clipping or wrapping and rounding issues. Also, if the operation casts to a float type, it is likely that the display mode will change: floats are often displayed with 1 and up as white, so you’ll get lots of clipping.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `addWeighted()` method in OpenCV

```
imgboth = cv2.addWeighted(imgh, 0.5, imgv, 0.5, 0)
```

Comment: This is not the same as the Euclidean norm of the gradient vector, which is what OP wants to compute. This computes `0.5*imgh + 0.5*imgv` rather than `(imgv**2 + imgv**2)**0.5`.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at this website: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html

Above answer seems to already provide the Gradient solution.

To add:

Gradient

```
addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad);
```

"We try to approximate the gradient by adding both directional gradients (note that this is not an exact calculation at all! but it is good for our purposes)."

Comment: Florian, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)